# smallest and greatest number (user enters -99 to stop input of numbers)

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that lets the user input a list of numbers and see what the greatest and smallest number they entered are. The amount of numbers the user can enter is only 2 (it needs to be however many they want until they enter -99 which marks the end of the list). I'm not sure how to repeat the process of entering a number until they enter -99. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated. (just as a reminder, -99 is NOT suppose to be part of the list, it should find the smallest and greatest number out of all the numbers BEFORE -99). I can only use loops to solve this.

```
int main(){

int firstNumber = 0;
int nextNumber = 0;
int greatestNumber = 0;

while (firstNumber != -99 || nextNumber != -99){
    cin >> firstNumber;
    if (firstNumber == -99){
        cout << "No numbers were entered." << endl;
        break;
    }
    greatestNumber = firstNumber;
    cin >> nextNumber;
    if (nextNumber == -99){
        cout << "the greatest number is " << firstNumber << endl;
        cout << "the smallest number is " << firstNumber << endl;
        break;
    }
    if (nextNumber > greatestNumber){
        greatestNumber = nextNumber;
        cout << "the greatest number is " << greatestNumber << endl;
        cout << "the smallest number is " << firstNumber << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "the greatest number is " << greatestNumber << endl;
        cout << "the smallest number is " << nextNumber << endl;
    }
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `while (firstNumber != -99 | nextNumber != -99)` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably meant `while (firstNumber != -99 && nextNumber != -99)`

Comment: oops i meant ||. I fixed it and even tried && but its still only allowing me to input 2 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`, you have only `currentNumber`. If it's greater than `greatestNumber` you assign it to `greatestNumber`. Then loop getting a new `currentNumber` and check again.

When the user end (which can happen in more ways than the user entering `-99`) you end the loop and print the greatest number.

Oh, and I suggest you initialize `greatestNumber` to something else than zero, at least if you want the user to be able to enter negative numbers (but bigger than `-99`).

As for the smallest number, have an equivalent variable `smallestNumber` that you initialize to a really big value (like [`std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)) and have an equa check for (but with less-than instead of greater-than).

---

Some pseudo-code:

```
int smallest = REALLY_BIG_NUMBER;
int largest = REALLY_SMALL_NUMBER;
int current;

loop while there is input to put in current
{
    if current is your exit condition then exit loop
    if current is larger than largest the reassign largest
    if current is smaller than smallest then reassign smallest
}

print largest and smallest
```

Comment: how would i check to see if currentNumber is greater than greatestNumber if i only have currentNumber? What am I doing to compare currentNumber with? There is no greatestNumber (yet)

Comment: @user3733575 Initialize `greatestNumber` to a really small value (e.g. [`std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min)) and always compare against that.

Comment: As OP manages the empty case, `largest` and `smallest` can be initialized with the first `current`.